# In Spring Web, how do I get the full URL of a @RestController?

Tags: java, spring

Lets say I inject an `ApplicationContext` into a bean. I can then discover all the beans annotated with `RestController`. How would I discover the base URL associated with said beans?

Example:

```
@Component
public class ServiceEnumerator {
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @PostConstruct
  private void postConstruct() {
    final Map<String, Object> beansToExpose = context.getBeansWithAnnotation(RestController.class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per standard, Base URL (Context root) needs to setup in configuration file.
Not sure if below will help you....Try to inject HttpServletRequest in controller then from controller, pass it to required service

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

LOGGER.info("URL "+httpRequest.getRequestURI());
```

will give /services/v1/hello if your URL is http://localhost:8080/services/v1/hello

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible by retrieving bean definition from bean factory and parsing its metadata. for instance:

- retrieve beanFactory from your application Context
- getting your bean definition from bean factory
- retrieving its metadata
- fetching attributes 
      `metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(
       "org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController")`